# Embed an ArcGIS Map in a Crystal Report

Tags: arcgis-10.0, reports

Is it possible to embed a map image inside a Crystal Report using ArcGIS 10?

I have seen articles about creating reports based off of map fields, but I would like to include an image of a selected area (i.e. a specific parcel on a map).

Is there a way to do this?